# JQuery selector to negate specific HTML elements within a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have HTML label structures generated by a JQuery multiselect dropdown library as shown:

```
<label for="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-1"><input id="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option-1" type="radio" value="DropDownVal1"><span>DropDownText1</span></label>
<label for="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-2"><input id="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option-2" type="radio" value="DropDownVal2"><span>DropDownText2</span></label>
```

My requirement is:  except the input element, whenever the user clicks on anywhere else in the

```
<label></label>
```

(including the label) area,I need to do `event.preventDefault()`. I have tried as

```
 $(document).on('click', 'label[for^="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But the above handler gets triggered even when I click on the `<input>` within the label as well(which is obvious and I know that!)

How do I write a JQuery selector for to filter this.

Comment: Why are you using a `<label>` when you don't want a `<label>`? O.o

Comment: Hello @Andreas. The markup is generated by JQuery multiselect library on which I need to write scripts to customize it's behavior

Comment: @surya Check out my answer.

Comment: Your JS example is missing the `on()` method name

Comment: @surya Also your `for` is messing up with the working of the whole logic.

Comment: @surya Oops. My bad then.

Comment: @Rory Made the code edits for the on(). Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman no problem sir. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to have the input out of the label... But:

> I do not have control over this markup structure... (your comment on another answer)

You can use [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) on the `<input>` elements... So the click event won't bubble up to the label.

See below... Try a click a label, then on a radio.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'label[for^="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-"]',function(event){
 console.log("Clicked on a label");
    event.preventDefault();  // Don't know if that is useful...
});

$(document).on('click', 'label[for^="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-"] input',function(event){
 console.log("Clicked on a radio input");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-1"><input id="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option-1" type="radio" value="DropDownVal1"><span>DropDownText1</span></label>
<label for="ui-multiselect-selectedSku-option-2"><input id="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option-2" type="radio" value="DropDownVal2"><span>DropDownText2</span></label>
```

Comment: your answer just fits in my requirement. Thank you so much. I cannot upvote your answer as I do not have enough reputations but your solution works for me. Thank you once again sir! :)

Comment: Good Day Louys. Accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is your label.  You generally should either have your input inside the label OR use the for attribute.  Your for attributes are for different controls than the ones inside the labels.  I am not sure how browsers will handle this.

If you don't want clicks on the label to trigger an input, don't associate them at all.  Consider not using a label at all, use a span instead.

If there is a condition that turns on/off whether the label affects a control, you can use code to set/clear the label's for attribute.

Comment: the above markup is generated by a JQuery Multiselect library. So I do not have control over this markup structure sir ! I only have the chance to control he behavior through JS/JQuery as far as I see.